# My terminal path in macOS SIerra is messed up

Tags: terminal, macos, bash, python, path

Few months ago, I was trying to download pygame on mac.

It was very difficult but I finally did it through terminal using bash.

But after the download, I think there was some change on default path on my Mac's terminal.

I searched many solutions through this site, but I can't solve the problem and I think those solutions are not really fit to my problem.

When I open terminal,

```
Last login: Thu Jul 6 21:18:59 on ttys000 ojeonghuns-MacBook-Pro:~ hoon$
```

I can see this kind of message and i remember that i couldn't find the first line when i first use terminal.

and on that state, i cannot use command line like ls, cd .. etc

I can use only pwd as i know, and everytime when I want to use ls or cd, i have to export new path by entering this kind of command line,

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
```

This leads me to use every command line, but everytime when i close and re-open the terminal, i have to set path.

If I echo $PATH , my path is

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:’/usr/local/bin:??
```

I think i download one or two additional Python versions on my Mac.

So is it possible to set default path ?

Oh, and when I try to figure out by typing  `open ~/.bash_profile`

I see the error message of

> Trace/BPT trap: 5

Answer (score 3):

The system's standard path (configured in /etc/paths) is `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. If you want to add an **additional** path like */Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin* to your user's PATH permanently you have to include the **old** $PATH in the *export PATH* line - either at the end or at the beginning - in your .bash_profile file:

- export PATH="new_path:$PATH"
- export PATH="$PATH:new_path"

Additionally your PATH contains some unwanted characters like `’` or `?` and doesn't have a closing quote `"`.

---

Open Terminal and enter:

```
/usr/bin/nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Change the line

```
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:’/usr/local/bin:??...
```

to

```
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:$PATH"
```

If the file contains another line with export PATH="..." squeeze the required parts into the above line.

Save the mod with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> and quit nano with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>

Quit and relaunch Terminal and enter `echo $PATH` which should reveal at least:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```